# draw a dot in a form on click event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Any help would be appreciated. How do I create a colored dot on a panel on where a user clicks his mouse? I can get the coordinates of the mouse click and output it through a message box but I can't draw the dot on the panel where the user clicked. I have these codes tried.

```
Private Sub createDot(x, y)
    MsgBox(x & " " & y)
    Dim myGraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics

    Dim myPen As Pen

    myPen = New Pen(Drawing.Color.Maroon, 20)

    myGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, x, y, 1, 1)

End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseClick
    missed += 1
    lblMissed.Text = missed
    Dim x, y As Integer
    x = e.X.ToString
    y = e.Y.ToString
    createDot(x, y)
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `ToString` thing? x, y must be integers not strings! You should do in `MsgBox`, `MsgBox(x.ToString() & " " & y.ToString())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things:

1.If you draw on panel you should use Panel1.CreateGraphics not  Me.CreateGraphics
2.The width of the pen is to large for a dot. Use 1 instead
3.Do not convert x, y to strings and pass it to createDot

**Caution:**
As soon as the panel is invalidated (for example you move another window over it) the dot will disappear. The drawing code should be in the Panel1_Paint event` (Scott Chamberlain)

```
Private Sub createDot(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)

    MsgBox(x.ToString & " " & y.ToString)
    Dim myGraphics As Graphics = Panel.CreateGraphics

    Dim myPen As Pen

    myPen = New Pen(Drawing.Color.Maroon, 1)

    myGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, x, y, 1, 1)

End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseClick
    missed += 1
    lblMissed.Text = missed

    createDot(e.x, e.y)
End Sub
```

Comment: 4.This method will not work very well because as soon as the panel is invalidated (for example you move another window over it then move it away) the dot will disappear. The drawing code should be in the `Panel1_Paint` event, the mouse click should just queue up some data structure the paint event reads so it knows where to paint then call `Panel1.Invalidate`.

Comment: Then it can be done like.....create global variables x,y and change there value in `mouse_down` event and in `paint event `.  Draw using `e.CreateGraphics`

Comment: @JavedAkram If you are in the paint event you don't need to call `CreateGrapics`, the paint event passes a graphics object in to the event for you pre-made as `Graphics` property of the PaintEventArgs. And the variables do not need to be global, they can be local to the Form/Control the OP is putting all these methods in.

Comment: You shouldn't use CreateGraphics _at all_.  As soon anything passes in front of the form or if the form is minimized/maximized, all graphics drawn with CreateGraphics will disappear!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create dot on panel you should change `Me.CreateGraphics` to `Panel1.CreateGraphics`

Remove ToString from
    `x=e.X`
    `y=e.Y`